# Difference between os.system("cmd") and commands.getoutput("cmd") ...?

Tags: python, command-line, output, os.system

I'm trying to print today's date using `os.sytem` and `commands.getoutput` using python.

My code is : 

    `import os, commands

    print os.system("date +%Y%m%d%T")
    print commands.getoutput("date +%Y%m%d%T")`

=========Ouput :-=============

**Case 1:**

`./test.py`

First print statement's O/P: 

`2014071713:25:21
0`

Second print statement's O/P:
`2014071713:25:21`

**Case 2:**
I tried trace using `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`

    `print os.system("date +%Y%m%d%T")
    (Pdb) n
    2014071713:25:21
    0

    print commands.getoutput("date +%Y%m%d%T")
    (Pdb) n
    2014071713:31:29
    --Return--`

Why first `print` statement appending `0` in both the cases and second `print` statement is not appending anything in `case 1` but it is appending `--Return--` in `case 2` ?

I know there are some modules for `date / time` in python but I want know why it is appending those extra strings in output ?

Comment: Have you read their documentation? And `commands` module was deprecated a long time ago, don't use it. And don't use `os.system` either, use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Comment: I know it is deprecated but I wanted to know reason for those O/P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `os.system` the return value is the called commands [return code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). The output of the called command is going straight to `stdout`

When you use `commands.getoutput` the called commands output is being captured, rather than going to stdout. The return code is not shown.

The easiest way to test the difference is to do:

```
a = os.system("some command")
b = commands.getoutput("some command")
print "commands have run"
print "output of os.system:",a
print "output of commands.getoutput",b
```

Note the `commands` module is depreciated. As noted in the comment above, you should look at using subprocess instead.